# When should I add a CancellationToken to an async interface method?

Tags: c#, cancellation-token

I am writing a C# interface which will have several different implementations, some of which I don't control. Given my problem domain, all (most of) the method implementations are going to involve some kind of network communication. For this reason, I am writing the interface so that all methods return instances of Task and can be run asynchronously. So far so good.

Now I am considering adding a `CancellationToken` parameter to some/all of the interface methods. AFAIK one should add a `CancellationToken` to a method when

- the method can take a long time, and
- there are points where the implementation can check the token and prevent further use of resources if the operation has been cancelled.

But it is not really clear to me what the criteria are when the method implementation is not known, e.g. when writing an interface. For example, some of the methods in my interface involve simple operations and are *probably* going to be fast enough not to need cancellation support in most cases, but I can't know for sure because I don't control all implementations, and in any case they will involve network communication so that will ultimately depend on network latency.

What are the rules of thumb/best practices to decide whether to add or not a `CancellationToken` to an interface method (whose implementation is unknown)?

Comment: Just keep it separate, define an ICancelable interface.  That a class may or may not implement, as deemed necessary.

Comment: This technically solves the design ambiguity, but it complicates the point of call - callers interested in cancellation need to check if they there is a cancellable method before calling it. I'd say that the naive criteria of always adding a CancellationToken is better - there is only one method to call, and the implementation can choose whether to handle cancellation or just ignore the token. But I'd like to see if there are cases where we can reasonably do without a token at all.

Comment: Passing a `CancellationToken` costs (practically) nothing, while retrofitting is a breaking change. The only bad path is when your method actually takes a long time, but *can't* be cancelled (due to limitations in the underlying implementation) -- this is bad news for the caller. At that point you have to decide if you want to leave it at that, or include a timeout that lets the operation "run away" in the background while still returning early. All other scenarios, in particular short, synchronous methods that don't check for cancellation except on entry, are not a real issue.

Comment: Extension methods make it trivial to offer overloads of the methods that pass `CancellationToken.None`, if this is expected to be a common use case for callers. Offering only methods without a CT in your interface practically commits implementations to making the execution short, and if that's the case a reasonable question is why the method should be `async` at all.